# Easy PSNR and SSIM calculation?

Tags: image-processing

I searched around the internet for a ready implementation/library for estimating 2 images by PSNR and SSIM, but found no real implementations for either. Are there really none or am I maybe missing some well known/obvious implementation? I really can't afford spending the time making my own implementations.
If anyone knows of any or has made any (preferrably with color support, not just b&w), let me know, ok (preferrably python, since it's convenient and accessible)?

Thank you.

edit: why was my question downvoted?

Comment: PSNR takes about one line in Matlab. Programming it would have used less of your precious time than posting your question. SSIM is easy to find too.

Comment: Yes, and I didn't know that, as I haven't used matlab and thanks to this answer I now do. Finding it out manually would have taken me much more time. I recommend finding a real reason to dislike.

Comment: The reason your question was down-voted (and why I downvoted you and closed your question) is because you express a complete lack of willingness to put any time into your own question. Please find some initiative and RTFM. You may, just, learn something.

Comment: I'm noticing a slight trend here - the higher the reputation number - the more conceited the individual. Honestly, it's a bit sad to see this kind of attitude still around in the 21st century, even if only in more obscure corners of the internet/society.
And I did put in the effort - I spent a good 2 minutes typing out the question. Before that I spent a good 10 minutes searching for my sought answer with no luck, so for once I decided to consult people that do this every day and, as evidenced, don't mind to share this info.
So, idk, get off your high horse and develop some empathy maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB, specifically R2015a in my case, has built-in ssim(A,ref), psnr(A,ref), and immse(A,ref) functions inside image processing toolbox and they are available for use in command window for greyscale images. You can try it for each channel as a color extension. If you insist on python, you might consider converting the available MATLAB library function into a Python script, yet it might take a while as well.